# Showing two windows in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

My friend and I have each created parts of a GUI using Qt 4. They both work independently and I am trying to integrate his form with the my main window.  As of now this is the code I am using to try and load his form:

```
//connect buttons and such
connect(exitbtn, SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(terminated()));
connect(add, SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(add_rec()));

void MainWindowImpl::add_rec()
{
  //form quits as soon as it loads...?
  DialogImpl dia;//name of his form
  dia.show();
}
```

I have included his header file.  The program compiles but when I hit the trigger his form loads up for maybe half a second and then closes.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens to dia at the end of add_rec?  When are local variables cleaned up?

Comment: To expand on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1705583/594137), it's your familiarity with C++ rather than Qt that's thrown you here. I'd suggest getting a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/594137) which covers the basics of C++ for times such as this.

Answer (score 2):

You have *almost* get it right. This is because the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) of C++. If you allocate the Dialog on stack, it would be destructed as soon as the function return.

Comment: Set dia as a MainWindowImpl member variable and just show it in the add_rec function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming MainWindowImpl inherits publically from QWidget, you're looking for this:

```
void MainWindowImpl::add_rec() 
{
  // passing "this" to the constructor makes sure dialog will be cleaned up.
  // Note that DialogImpl will need a constructor that takes a
  // QObject* parent parameter.
  DialogImpl* dialog = new DialogImpl(this);

  dialog->show(); 
}
```

Look at the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qwidget.html#QWidget) for examples of how the constructors should look.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently QT4 only allows one instance of an object at a time, however pointers are another matter.  Change both the main.cpp *and* what ever your main window to look something like this:

```
DialogImpl *dia=new DialogImpl;
dia->show();
```

Comment: This is wrong.  The problem is that dia is getting destructed at the end of the function.  (Qt4 definitely allows you to have multiple instances of a class at a time.)